# What do the symbols "(", ")", "[", and "]" mean when speaking about ranges of numbers?

Tags: math, numbers, range

Google isn't being helpful for me today, and the StackOverflow search is returning no results. However, this could be the result of inefficient keyword usage.

My question is: when speaking of a range of numbers in a programming language, what do the symbols "(", ")", "[", and "]" mean?

For example, (0, 10], or [0, 10).

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236125/get-random-integer-in-range-x-y), where the referenced symbols are used both in the title and question text.

My theory is that "(" and ")" mean "excluding" and "[" and "]" mean "including". Is this a correct hypothesis?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java (or its use of such symbols) - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Comment: @LiorKogan May I know why, exactly?

Comment: Can I know why this was downvoted? ("Not useful, shows no effort, badly formatted, etc"?)

Comment: @hmc_jake: It got nothing to do with programming. http://math.stackexchange.com/ is much more suitable.

Comment: @LiorKogan When I asked the question, I did not know that it was not programming-specific and that it was, in-fact, mathematics-specific. I thought this was programming lingo, so that's why I asked here. I think a move vote (if those exist) would be better than a close vote. And I especially don't believe I deserve to have my reputation damaged over this with downvote(s).

Comment: @hmc_jake: I agree, it doesn't deserve downvotes, But don't take it so hard. The important thing is that you now know the answer ;-)

Comment: @LiorKogan Would it be better to just delete this myself, then?

Comment: @hmc_jake: I think you can't delete it if it has an upvoted answer. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematical notations, not programming.

Comment: why doesn't your math text book teach about this?

Answer (score 3):

After viewing the article (provided by a commenter) on Intervals (a mathematical concept), I was able to determine the answer. ([See the article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)).)

As defined by the article, an **open interval** (uses "(" and ")") means that the interval **does not** include its endpoints (i.e. `excluding` a number.) A **closed interval** (uses "[" and "]") means that the interval **does** include its endpoints (i.e. `including` a number.)

With these defined, then with the examples included in the question:

- **(0, 10]** means **greater than (and not including)** *zero* and **including** *ten*.
- **[0, 10)** means **greater than (and including)** *zero* and **less than** *ten*.

Comment: "greater than (and not including)" = "greater than"; "greater than (and including)" = "greater than or equal to"

Comment: It's not clear from context whether you're talking about intervals on the real line, or whether your domain is restricted to integers.  The interval `(0, 10]` contains `0.5`, which is not greater than (or greater than or equal to) `1`.  "(Strictly) greater than zero" would be a better description of that endpoint.  As @user2864740 already noted, the "strictly" here is unnecessary (though perhaps helpful for emphasis).

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thank you. I updated the answer.